# create project permission denied in htdocs

Tags: zend-framework, zend-server

I just downloaded the Zend Server on Windows 7. When I try and create a project in the apache2/htdocs folder, I get the following error statement:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs>zf create project newproject
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServ
er\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Tool\Project\Provider\Project.php on line 55


Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\sh
are\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Tool\Project\Provider\Project.php on line 55
                     An Error Has Occurred
Could not create requested project directory 'newproject'

Zend Framework Command Line Console Tool v1.11.10
Details for action "Create" and provider "Project"
Project
  zf create project path name-of-profile file-of-profile
```

Any idea what that's about?

Comment: Does your user have permission to write to that directory? By default they wont without escalating to admin.

Comment: Doesn't look like it. Should I uninstall the server and reinstall it outside of my program files directory?

Comment: I would jsut create group and add wrx permissions to that group for the folder, then add yourself to that group... or just give your specific user wrx access. Im not really sure if thats the best practice though on Windows - its rare that i ever work on or configure anything windows related beyond browser testing in VMs :-)

Comment: It's exactly what the error says: mkdir() is not possible which means you need to start your shell as admin and/or change permissions on the htdocs folder.

Comment: gave myself write permissions on the zend folder and that solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to make it official

The user which you're using to create the project doesn't have write permissions on *C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs>*, by the way, only admins have write permissions on *C:\Program Files (x86)* and it's subfolders by default.

To give yourself write permissions:

1. Right click this folder from the explorer
2. Select "properties"
3. Go to the "security" tab
4. Click on the "advanced" button
5. In the "permissions" tab make sure that your user has write/modify permission

That should do the trick!